# SessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals() return empty list

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have config my spring security as follow:

root-context

```
        <import resource="classpath:springConfig.xml" />
    <import resource="appServlet/servlet-context.xml" />
    <import resource="appServlet/spring-security.xml" />

    <bean id="InitializationService"
        class="kh.com.gfam.rsos.businesslogic.initialization.impl.InitializationServiceImpl">
    </bean>



    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages_en"></property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Custom Spring Security -->

    <bean id="companyIdUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider"
        class="kh.com.gfam.rsos.common.security.RsosAuthenticationProvider" />

    <bean id="companyIdUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
        class="kh.com.gfam.rsos.common.security.RsosUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/Authenticate" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <constructor-arg value="/Login" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationFailureHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/Login/defaultError" />
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop
                    key="org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException">
                    /Login/badCredentials
                </prop>
                <prop
                    key="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException">
                    /Login/userNotFound
                </prop>
                <prop
                    key="org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException">
                    /Login/disabled
                </prop>
                <prop
                    key="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException">
                    /Login/providerNotFound
                </prop>
                <prop
                    key="org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException">
                    /Login/authenticationService
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        class="kh.com.gfam.rsos.common.security.RsosAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    </bean>

    <bean id="RsosLogoutSuccessHandler"
        class="kh.com.gfam.rsos.common.security.RsosLogoutSucessHandler"></bean>

    <bean id="concurrencyFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
        <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <constructor-arg name="expiredUrl" value="/session-expired.jsp" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

    <bean id="sas"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />
                    <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
                    <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
                </bean>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy" />
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true"
        entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">  
        <intercept-url pattern="/Admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/Concierge/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
        <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"
            ref="companyIdUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter" />  
        <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
        <logout logout-url="/Logout" delete-cookies="true"
            invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="RsosLogoutSuccessHandler" />
        <csrf disabled="true" />
        <session-management invalid-session-url="/Login"
            session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />

        <access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied" />
    </http>

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider
            ref="companyIdUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider" />  
    </authentication-manager>
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>webapp.root</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.WebAppRootListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>kh.com.gfam.rsos.listener.InitializeApplicationListner</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <multipart-config>
            <max-file-size>10485760</max-file-size>
            <max-request-size>104857600</max-request-size>
            <file-size-threshold>20971520</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>
    </servlet>



    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>GetImageController</display-name>
        <servlet-name>GetImageController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>kh.com.gfam.rsos.presentation.controller.GetImage.GetImageController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GetImageController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/GetImageController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/error_pages/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>405</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/error_pages/405.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/error_pages/500.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/error_pages/400.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/error_pages/system_error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

spring-config.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mybatis-spring:scan base-package="kh.com.gfam.rsos.dataaccess.dao.**" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">
        </property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rsosdb">
        </property>
        <property name="username" value="admin"></property>
        <property name="password" value="gfam"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:messages_en.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:email.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:emailtemplate.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        </bean>
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatisConfig.xml">
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.sivalabs.mybatisdemo.mappers" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver">
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
        <property name="cookieName" value="myAppLocaleCookie"></property>
        <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="3600"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- mail configuration -->
     <bean class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl"
        id="mailSender">
        <property name="host" value="${email.host}" />
        <property name="protocol" value="${email.protocol}" />
        <property name="port" value="${email.port}" />
        <property name="username" value="${email.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${email.password}" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.trust">${email.host}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean> 

    <bean class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage" id="orderRequestReceivedTemplate">
        <property name="subject" value="${email.subject.request.received}" />
        <property name="text" value="${email.text.request.received}" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage" id="cancelRequestRecievedTemplate">
        <property name="subject" value="${email.subject.request.canceled}" />
        <property name="text" value="${email.subject.request.canceled}" />
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
        <property name="warnLogCategory" value="apperror" />
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.lang.Exception">error</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

servlet-context

```
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"
        order="1" ignore-unresolvable="true" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="kh.com.gfam.rsos" />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="kh.com.gfam.rsos.businesslogic.initialization.impl" />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="kh.com.gfam.rsos.businesslogic.displaymenuservice.impl" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="kh.com.gfam.rsos.common.util" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="kh.com.gfam.rsos.common.security" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="kh.com.gfam.rsos.presentation.controller" />
```

code in controller

```
    List<Object> allPrincipals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();

    for(Object principal : allPrincipals) {
        if(principal instanceof UserDTO) {
            final UserDTO user = (UserDTO) principal;

            // Do something with user
            System.out.println(user);
        }
    }
```

When I tried to call sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals() in my controller it always return the empty list, and I have already autowired the SessionRegistry and have override the method equal() and hashCode() in my UserDTO class which is implemented from UserDetail too.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Post your web.xml and the xml of your context loaded by the  `DispatcherServlet`. My guess is you are loading everything twice hence getting a wrong reference to a not used `SessionRegistry`.

Comment: I edited my post and add both of them, can you point out the mistake?

Comment: Why are you loading `servlet-context.xml` twice? That basically duplicates all the beans in there. Please add that configuration. Currently the information is incomplete.

Comment: I edit my post again and add the servlet context to it, please check.
By the way this configuration was touch and edit by my team, so maybe one of them the import the servlet-context into the root-context.xml.

Comment: I have a hard time wrapping my head around your configuration, there is a lot of duplication (xml file loaded twice, component-scanning done multiple times). I would suggest to enable debug logging and check what is happening during startup how often classes are instantiated.

Comment: @M. Deinum, Thank you very much i have a similar issue of getting sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals() to work. i found that i am loading one of the configuration class twice both in getRootConfigClasses & in getServletConfigClasses. your above comments helped me to resolve the issue and now it is working fine.